# CakePHP 3: Ajax response is returning a 200 response code and a parsererror

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm attempting to send an ajax request from a javascript file to a cakephp controller. The ajax is sending a simple json object (I've hardcoded it in this example for simplicity).

When I do logging, the server is able to decode the json string into an object. The `$this->Votes->delete` function is called successfully. My problem is that everything works as it should, except I'm still getting an error message anyways.

Below is my code, and below that is the output that I get from it.

Javascript:

```
function unvote() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../votes/unvote',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({'post_id':1}),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }.
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // this block gets triggered with a 200 response
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
    });
}
```

PHP: Votes Controller

```
public function unvote(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $vote = $this->Votes->newEntity();
    if ( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        $data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
        $vote = // get the correct vote from the database and save into this object
        if ( $this->Votes->delete($vote) ) {
            $this->response->body('Success');
            $this->response->statusCode(200);
        } else {
            $this->response->body('Failure');
            $this->response->statusCode(500);
        }
    }
    $this->response->type('json');
    return $this->response;
}
```

ajax Response:

```
Object{ readyState=4, responseText="", status=200, statusText="Ok", more...}
parsererror
SyntaxError:JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
> return window.JSON.parse( data + "" );
```

Comment: Did you send an correct `header("Content-Type: application/json", true);` and why are you doing `window.JSON.parse`? Because you are expecting via `dataType: 'json'` json data, so it will be parsed be jquery, you dont have to parse it by yourself.

Comment: I thing your response is invalid, check request log via F12 in the Browser (Developer Console -> network tab)

Comment: `status=200` has to do with the http call, not the given data itself. Status 200 means here: Something was send correct. Nothing more. That says nothing about the content that was send.

Comment: I just added the json header, still has the same behavior. I was looking the the Developer Console and the `errorThrown` printed out the part about the `window.JSON.parse` I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Better look into the network-tab, look there for the ajax call `../votes/unvote` and check the response-data there. Or call the ajax request, directly in the browser to get the json data, like `../votes/unvote?post_id=1`

Comment: I think we may be on to something in the Net tab. I must first click an upvote button, which creates an `POST upvote` however when I click it again I would expect a `POST unvote` but there is not. I still get the console messages for the unvote, just not an entry for the unvote in the Net tab.

Comment: Sounds buggy, cant help more from here. But try to ensure that you are getting valid ajax data.

Comment: Maybe remove this lines `contentType: 'application/json', dataType: 'json',` and send no `header()` for testing. Then you get plain text as response and you can check it. im out :)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Removing the contentType and dataType fixed the problem! Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery ajax function is expecting a json object and you aren't giving it json**

Here are some suggestions for working with ajax in cakephp

- I wouldn't set autorender to false. Instead create an ajax layout.
- You need to set the _serialize view variable if you want to return data

I would suggest doing something like this.

```
$responseData = ['success' => true];
$this->set('responseData', $responseData);
$this->set('_serialize', ['responseData']);
```

Obligatory references from the docs

[JSON and XML Data Views](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)

> There are two ways you can generate data views. The first is by using the _serialize key, and the second is by creating normal template files

[Using Data Views](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key)

> The _serialize key is a special view variable that indicates which other view variable(s) should be serialized when using a data view.